# Create Code Snippet for Method Comments

Tags: c++, comments, visual-studio-2013, code-snippets

I'm trying to make a code snippet using the Snippet Manager in Visual Studio 2013 for C++. The code snippet would ideally provide a C#-like comment template for methods. Suppose the following method:

```
void MyMethod( int a, float b );
```

I would like you to be able to type something like `comment` on the line above the method, press tab, and have the following populate:

```
// 
// Describe 'MyMethod' here.
// - a: Describe 'a' here.
// - b: Describe 'b' here.
// 
void MyMethod( int a, float b );
```

I have the following so far for my snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Comment</Title>
            <Shortcut>cmt</Shortcut>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>MethodDetails</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Describe the intent of the method here.</ToolTip>
                    <Default>Describe your method here.</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="cpp">
                <![CDATA[// 
                // $MethodDetails$
                // ]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

My question is: **is it possible to auto-generate the template stubs for the parameters of the method below the snippet?** and if so, **how do I generate those?**

Comment: Do you need that format exactly? Are you familiar with the XML comments?

Comment: Well the XML comments in VS are fairly verbose for no real gain. I understand the purpose in .Net because it translates into IntelliSense, but we're just trying to develop a standard that looks slim and could potentially be parsed.

Comment: They are parseable, and can be slimmed.
`/// <summary>This is an informative method description</summary>`
`/// <param name="param1">Parameter description</param>`
`/// <returns>Vizzini said to the beginning</returns>`